# unable to install ubuntu on alongside windows 10. Grub install /dev/sda failed

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Note:  I have already checked all the answers available on stackoverflow and various other forums. But could find no solution that would help me solve "grub install /dev/sda failed fatal error"

I have made sure the UEFI mode is selected and not legacy.
Secure boot is off.
Fastboot is turned off.

There is one partition(sda 6 for ubuntu). sda 1 EFI for as windows boot manager(And assuming that grub will be installed here). I am using live usb to install Ubuntu.

I have also tried with and without a new EFI drive sda4. Please help me resolve this and get Ubuntu 16.04 installed

I have attached the screenshots for reference.

[image: UEFI Boot selected]

[image: partition list]

Comment: Did you notice a warning message about installing in UEFI mode during the process? If so what did you do?

Comment: There's something weird about your sda though. The first "EFI System" partition looks right, 500MB. There should be only one per drive and yet your show a second 4.7GB "EFI System" partition??

Comment: @CelticWarrior I added the second one assuming that would somehow install the grub in the secind EFI. I am sure it is wrong. But I assure you I did not work and showed the same error even before the new partition was made

Comment: Yes, unrelated but you should remove that monstrosity anyway (use the space to create perhaps a NTFS shared data partition accessible from both Ubuntu and Windows).

Comment: Sure... Any other ideas?

Comment: You also need to boot Windows and disable *fast startup* - https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html - and shutdown (reboot will undo the changes). Then, and only then booot the Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode and use something else to manage partitions. You want to use and format the current sda6 for / (root) but you also should have some swap (you can use part of the EFI you've made and give it ~2GB just to have some). Also mark the real EFI partition for use but NOT format, obviously.

Comment: I will try this then

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same problem while trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1 Pro. However, make sure you uncheck *Turn off secure boot*, and then reboot your computer. After that press <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> depending on your computer, then make sure you boot in UEFI and not Legacy.

After installing Ubuntu, reboot the system. If it chooses Ubuntu automatically and didn't show the GRUB boot loader, this means you have to do one more step.

In Ubuntu, after logging in:

- Connect to the Internet.
- Open a new Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then type the following commands (press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each line):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
  ```

This boot manager will help uninstalling the old version of GRUB and reinstalling a new version of it. Just follow its steps.

I hope I solved your problem. If there's anything else, please leave a comment.

Comment: I will try this and let you know if it works